# Copy and replace strings from 1 text file to another in batch MS OS

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing

I would like to copy and replace strings from 1 text file to another one and echo the output to new text file. Sound simple but i have to say that i really got confused about the logic method. Any help is welcome.

copy 3 words from 3 lines (1 for each) in the first txt file --> replace each word for the relevant string in the other txt file.*

Thanks.

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%z in (from.txt) do (
set resulta=%%z
)
for /f  "delims=" %%x in (workwith.txt) do (
set _alla=%%x
set _firstcombine=!_alla:8150=%resulta%!
echo _firstcombine >> move1.txt
)
for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%v in ('findstr /C:"2016" from.txt') do (
set _result=%%v
set _outp=!_result:~52!
)
for /f  "delims=" %%f in ('findstr /C:"2016" move1.txt') do (
set _allz=%%f
set _txo=!_all:~170,-255!
set _secondcombine=!_allz:%_txo%=%_outp%!
echo _secondcombine >> move2.txt
)
for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%j in ('findstr /C:"Wanaka," from.txt') do (
set _resultn=%%j
)
for /f  "delims=" %%l in ('findstr /C:"xxx" move2.txt') do (
set _allf=%%l
set _to=!_all:~52!
set _thirdcombine=!_allf:%_to%=%_resultn%!
echo _thirdcombine >> move3.txt
)
pause
```

Comment: Could you provide an example of some input and your desired output?

Comment: you obviously know, how to use variables. Why don't you do it with your `echo` lines (`echo !_firstcombine!` etc.)?

Answer (score 0):

my input is 3 lines of some arbitrary strings (including numeric ones).
each line supposed to copy to the other file in specific place in each line of the new file.
this first 3 lines form the input is set 1, there will be some X sets according to division by 3.

SO: file input, file output which waiting for the input lines to be place inside the lines of output file and sets.

Thanks! :)